# Connect SonarQube to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube

I want to use a PostgreSQL database for the Sonar reports.

I follow the steps here [Sonar with PostgreSQL](http://www.tecnohobby.net/ppal/index.php/programacion/java/28-instalar-sonarqube-con-postgresql)

But I get this error in the logs, how can I solve this problem:

```
2017.10.12 21:38:47 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
    2017.10.12 21:38:47 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: C:\Users\Azubi\Desktop\Sonar\sonarqube-6.2\web
    2017.10.12 21:38:48 INFO  web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
    2017.10.12 21:38:48 ERROR web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:742)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:458)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:345)
        at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:62)
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:41)
        at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:102)
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:67)
    2017.10.12 21:38:48 ERROR web[][o.a.c.c.StandardService] Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9000]]
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9000]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:345)
        at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:62)
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:41)
        at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:102)
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:67)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        ... 10 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:742)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:458)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
        ... 11 common frames omitted
    2017.10.12 21:38:48 WARN  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
    java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
        at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
        at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:65)
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:41)
        at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:102)
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:67)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:345)
        at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:62)
        ... 3 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        ... 6 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9000]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:575)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        ... 8 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you post your sonar.properties file ?
The message here is that the web server cannot bind on port 9000 because another process has already bound the 9000 port. Maybe you launched SonarQube twice or you have another process using the port 9000.

Answer (score 0):

If you have docker, then running sonar server with postgres is really easy.
Just follow [these instructions](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/blob/master/recipes.md). If you can not use port 9000, you should replace the line

```
- "9000:9000"
```

With e.g.

```
- "9001:9000"
```

in order to reach sonar server at port 9001